# How to create a dynamic $this call?

Tags: php

**Eddited:**
I have a class. 
I the class cunstructor I retrive all the row data from a table
like this:

```
$this->isalonefile = $row['isalonefile'];
$this->tzfile = $row['tzfile'];
```

The table have two columns: `tzfile` and `isalonefile`
In one of the methods I want to dynamically choose between the two values above

for example(this is very simplified...):

```
public function foo($var){
           if($var == 'tzfile'){
              $val = $this->tzfile;
           }elseif($var == 'isalonefile'){
              $val = $this->isalonefile;
           }
        }
```

I want to create a dynamic method like

```
      public function foo($var){

              $val = $this->$var;

   }
```

How can it be done?

Comment: What has this to to with PDO at all? Please clarify your question, so that we know 1.) What you expect it to do, 2.) What it actually does and 3.) What you've tried so far to solve your problem. Also, provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What you are attempting to do is an extremely harmful practice. Don't do this.

Comment: Did I tagged PDO? So it was probably a mistake.I will edit the question.

Comment: If your talking about variable variables (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) then try `$var = "file";`.  BUT this is usually a sign of some design problem, arrays can provide a much better solution in a lot of cases.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Looks like it should do what you want already

Comment: The problem I that I have like 20 cases in the foo method. I thought there may be a better and easier way to call the spesific value I need using something like this:   `$val = $this->$var;`

Answer (score 0):

If $this is your class instance you can only access the methods and attributes of this class instance. I think it doesn't make sense to get a new variable for an existing attribute. This would make your code unreadeble.

Better get the access of your attributes and methods directly.